# Facebook Login Redirect PHP/Javascript Not Working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, redirect, authentication

I've looked through many posts on the site, but was still unable to get Facebook login and redirect working. When a user logs in via Facebook by pressing a button on a webpage, I want to automatically redirect them to another webpage and pass their email and password through via the url. Unfortunately, I've only got it to work to the point that when they login, I have to manually reload the page to get them to the redirect page by refreshing my webpage. I was wondering if someone could post code on how to do this? I've tried moving things around a lot.

```
<?php

 //uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
 require 'facebook.php';

define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'xxxx');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxx',
   'secret' => 'xxxx',
  ));   

?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="user-info"></div>
     <div class="fb-login-button" style="position:absolute;top:800px;">Login with Facebook</div>




<script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({ appId: 'xxxx', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true});

  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
      + response.id + '/picture">' + response.email;
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';

             });
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML="";
    });
      };






} 



    else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      button.innerHTML = 'Login';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML = 
                '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
            + response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' 
            + response.name;


        });    
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:'email'});    
      }
    }
  }


  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());





</script>

<?php

   $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    if($uid != 0) {
        header("Location: signup.php");
      }   

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Primarily using `header('Location')` for a facebook application does not work.

I am assuming the rest of the code is working and thus the only change required would be

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
if($uid != 0) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='your-login-url'</script>");
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the response, but it still does not automatically redirect the user. I have to manually refresh the page to get to the redirect page. Do you know how I can get this to work automatically?